# Upgraded EF5 to EF 6 and now get "Cannot find the object because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

I've got a main web application project using a referenced class library that uses EF code first. In the main web application I've also got several .edmx files. This is a production app with real data using automatic migrations (MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion).

I just upgraded from EF 5 to EF 6. There were no class/context changes at all between upgrading. I simply upgraded and fixed my .edmx files. No compile time errors. Yet when I try my main app I get the following error:

> Cannot find the object "dbo.FormItemResponseFormItemAnswers" because
>   it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Now I've double checked my database and the table should and does in fact exist and the login uses to connect has dbo permissions on the database as they did before the upgrade. So I have no idea why I am getting this error. Nothing changed. The stack trace looks like so:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object "dbo.FormItemResponseFormItemAnswers" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1767866
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352418
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +869
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +410
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +36
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +138
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +476
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +177
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +307
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +59
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +110
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection) +799
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClass30.b__2e() +66
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +34
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +251
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +196
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction) +326
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements) +39
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements) +42
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto) +1335
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading) +1358
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading) +64
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +741
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +59
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) +888
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b() +38
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +516
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +42
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +136
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update() +33
>      System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +154
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__e() +165
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +110
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +660
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext c) +31
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +143
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +292
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +123
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +41
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +137
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +38
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +99
>      System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +63

I haven't found anyone else with this problem. Can someone shed some light? I've no clue what to do and the usual google reveals mostly SQL errors with having no relation to EF.

Again nothing in the context/objects changed nor were any manual changes done to the database. I double checked my source control. I can't tell from the stack trace if it's trying to run a migration or not but I use automatic migration and it shouldn't be attempting to migrate because nothing changed.

EDIT: I know the _MigrationHistory table stores the EF version number in it and all mine are currently 5.0.0.net45. Is it possible it's trying to create a new migration history record for v6? But again, no context change I don't know what's it's trying to do with that table.

Answer (score 0):

try delete the database , and recreate again

or try to implement
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Comment: Yeah no way that's happening, this is a production database with real data being used on a live web app.

Comment: Sorry I doesnt know that. at the same way you can execute  a migration .  weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/using-entity-framework-4-3-database-migration-for-any-project

Answer (score 0):

Automatic migrations are not supposed to be used outside of testing/development. You also should be running your upgrading process against a production-like copy or clone, not the actual production database. I imagine that disabling automatic migration and forcing a normal migration with `>Add-Migration` and then `>Update-Database` might resolve this issue.